# Mapbox Studio transparent water

Tags: mapbox, tilemill, cartocss

I have a problem with Mapbox Studio. I'd like to make water layer appear transparent and land area in some color. When I remove or modify the Map {} background to be transparent, all the change to transparent except water which remains to the color it is set to. If i try adding fox example, #countries { polygon-fill: #ff0000 }, it does nothing to fill the land covered area.

I have failed to find any good reference to what would work for the current version of Mapbox. The things that work for tilemill does not seem to work for Mapbox Studio. Any pointers or advises would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I should note that modifying nearly every other layer to the desired fill color get almost satisfactory results, but still shoreline is not colored as it should, but coloring usually starts from #hillshade or other layer. As far as I can tell there is no layer which is ending to #water -layer. Can this really be the case or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

In Mapbox Studio Classic (desktop application), `Map` refers to all of the land, and (if you're using `mapbox-streets-v5` or `mapbox-streets-v6` as your data source) `#water` has its own selector. If you set `Map` to some color value, all of the land will be that color. If you set `#water` to some color value, all of the water will be that color. Keep in mind also that rivers and streams can be styled via the `#waterway` selector.